# yauzl, fromBuffer and know when it's done

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using yauzl to read a zip-file from 1 S3 bucket and to stream the content (unzipped) to another S3 bucket.

This is all done via a `Lambda function` and I want to integrate it with `AWS Pipeline` as well.

I am using the `.fromBuffer` method, as the `S3.getObject` method returns a `Buffer`.  Unfortunately, in that scenario, the 'end' event is never emitted.

Are there other ways to know when that operation has finished?  The reason I'm asking is that the outcome should be communicated to `CodePipeline`, otherwise I never know if the operation has finished successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the '.fromBuffer' does emit an 'end'-event. So you can use it, even though the docs state it doesn't work that way.

Comment: It does emit 'end' event before streams end reading. I have this problem now. I don't know when to resolve a promise because of that.